# Using cd to go up multiple directory levels

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm dealing with java projects which often result in deeply nested folders (/path/to/project/com/java/lang/whatever, etc) and sometimes want to be able to jump, say, 4 directory levels upwards. Typing cd ../../../.. is a pain, and I don't want to symlink. Is there some flag to cd that lets you go up multiple directory levels (in my head, it would be something like cd -u 4)? Unfortunately I can't find any man page for cd specifically, instead just getting the useless "builtins" page.

Comment: Modifying bash to interpret `cd ...` where the number of '.' would be the number of levels to go up.  Would this cause a conflict that I'm not aware of?

Comment: For those coming here for MacOS you can install `zsh` and `Oh My Zsh` which is a better alternative to `bash` and then you can just do `cd ...` (multiple dots) like it should be

Answer (score 46):

A simple function, with an alias, too:

```
function cd_up() {
  cd $(printf "%0.s../" $(seq 1 $1 ));
}
alias 'cd..'='cd_up'
```

(You could define this in `~/.bashrc` if you want it in every instance).

It's simple to use:

```
$ cd.. 10
```

Comment: Nice one! Works for me! Bash 4.3.11

Comment: Good answer; you might want to point out that this is better than solutions such as `eval $(printf "cd ..;%.s" $(seq $1))` which `cd` multiple times, because `~-` aka `$OLDPWD` is set to the working directory from before invocation, rather than to an intermediate directory.  P.S. - it simplifies to `cd $(printf %.s../ $(seq "$1"))` if you want.

Answer (score 37):

Or... try this: (yay Google)

> Navigate up the directory using ..n :
>
> In the example below, ..4 is used to go up 4 directory level, ..3 to
>   go up 3 directory level, ..2 to go up 2 directory level.
>
> Add the following alias to the .bash_profile and re-login.
>
> alias ..="cd .."
>
> alias ..2="cd ../.."
>
> alias ..3="cd ../../.."
>
> (etc)

See [Hack #2](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/6-awesome-linux-cd-command-hacks-productivity-tip3-for-geeks/)

Comment: I would rather use the aliases `..`, `...` and `....` as they are faster to type, but the principle of aliases is the same of course.

Comment: @bernhard You're more than welcome to, as I don't believe it would cause any conflicts. I just left it as-is because I quoted it from the website.

Comment: The 4DOS.EXE shell for DOS also supported `cd ...`, `cd ....` etc. It was very handy.

Comment: ..... is not faster than ..4 , in fact it is 2 characters slower..

Comment: I would argue that `....` is faster than `..3`, since it's a repeated keystroke. And I'm not likely to navigate up more than 3 directories at a time. In fact, I normally only use `..` or `...`, since I can't mentally walk my file system in jumps of 3 or more.

Answer (score 21):

A simple, low-tech solution that doesn't need any setup. Only works in shells with `bash`-style command editing, though.

- Type `cd ..`
- Press <kbd>Up-arrow</kbd> <kbd>Return</kbd> as many times as needed. Very fast if you use two fingers.

Comment: haha, not a bad answer i guess :)

Comment: I prefer this solution, sweet and easy. :P

Answer (score 10):

Turns out the correct answer is 'cd +n', where n is the number of levels you want to go up. Too bad this isn't documented anywhere!

Comment: at least it does NOT work in bash.

Comment: Doesn't work on bash 4.2.25 as shipped with Debian. Out of curiosity, what *nix and/or shell are you using?

Comment: Bash has a built-in called `dirs` that takes [+n] as an argument, and prints the nth unique directory that was added via `pushd`. If you `alias` `cd` to `pushd`, then you can use this.

However, note that this is not technically an answer to the OP's question, because this has to do with *unique* directories, meaning that the order gets messed up over time, as you return to the same directories.

Comment: Yeah, `pushd` and `popd` also take a [+n] option, which is why that is able to work. Also, though it's imperfect and indirect, I guess this can be used as an answer to the question. Often you visited the directories above you recently, so they will be in the last 10 dirs stored by the directory stack.

Comment: did not work for me...

Answer (score 7):

You could write a function (it has to be a function, as you want to change the state of your shell itself, namely the working directory; an external command would affect only its own process).

Here's a function that will go up a number of levels passed as argument (default 1):

```sh
up() {
    # default parameter to 1 if non provided
    declare -i d=${@:-1}
    # ensure given parameter is non-negative. Print error and return if it is
    (( $d < 0 )) && (>&2 echo "up: Error: negative value provided") && return 1;
    # remove last d directories from pwd, append "/" in case result is empty
    cd "$(pwd | sed -E 's;(/[^/]*){0,'$d'}$;;')/";
}
```

Use it like this:

```sh
up 4
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Agreed, I have added a few comments to help.

Comment: To be nitpicky, isn't ```up 4``` really equivalent to ```cd /some/dir/``` assuming ```$PWD = "/some/dir/that/is/deeply/nested/"```?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you're asking for but you should look into `pushd` and `popd`. I find them much more useful for folder navigation than some `cd...` alias

If you're going back and forth from a couple fixed areas, the usual thing is to have aliases.

```
alias proj1='cd /some/dir/containing/proj1'
alias proj2='cd /some/deeper/dir/structure/containing/proj2'
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using aliases you could also use the following bash function:

```
function mcd() {
  up=""

  for ((i=1; i<=$1;i++)); do
    up="${up}../"
  done

  cd $up
}
```

(or as a one-liner: `function mcd() { up=""; for ((i=1; i<=$1;i++)); do up="${up}../"; done; cd $up; }`)

Adding this to your `~/.bashrc` file will make it available in your terminal and the building of a String `../../../../../../` before calling `cd` will also make it possible to use `cd -` to jump back to the start directory.

A more helpful implementation could also contain some user-input checks:

```
function mcd() {
    if [[ $1 -lt 1 ]]; then
        echo "Only positive integer values larger than 1 are allowed!" >&2
        echo -e "\n\tUsage:\n\t======\n\n\t\t# to go up 10 levels in your directory\n\t\tmcd 10\n\n\t\t# to go up just 2 levels\n\t\tmcd 2\n" >&2
        return 1;
    fi  

    up=""

    for ((i=1; i<=$1;i++)); do
        up="${up}../"
    done

    cd $up
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax proposed in the answers are frankly unintuitive and meh.

You should be able to go back simply by repeating the period i.e. `cd ...` or `cd ....`

https://github.com/parkercoates/dotfiles/blob/master/.zsh/expand-multiple-dots.zsh

or

https://github.com/knu/zsh-manydots-magic

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump)? It's a third party hack, but can be useful in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try the rarely used environment parameter `CDPATH`. Then you might not have to explicitly set the level.

Example:

```
$ find workspace -type d
workspace
workspace/project1
workspace/project1/com
workspace/project1/com/java
workspace/project1/com/java/lang

$ CDPATH=".:~/workspace:~/workspace/project1:~/workspace/project1/com:~/workspace/project1/com/java:~/workspace/project1/com/java/lang"
$ cd com
$ pwd
~/workspace/project1/com
```

If working on multiple projects, you can make the CDPATH setting into a project specific environment file. And trigger it with a shim for additional automation.

I tend to use pushd and popd quite a lot. I tend to use CDPATH to let me hop between project trees rather than subdirs in a project - but at the moment I'm working on a lot of small projects, not a few big projects. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are previously on the target directory:

```
luna:/tmp % mkdir -p a/b/c/d
luna:/tmp % pwd
/tmp
luna:/tmp % cd a/b/c/d
luna:d % pwd
/tmp/a/b/c/d
luna:d % cd -
luna:/tmp % pwd
/tmp
luna:/tmp %
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DirB](https://github.com/icyfork/dirb). It's a BASH script that allows you to create bookmarks as follows:

OPERATIONS

- s       Save a directory bookmark
- g       go to a bookmark or named directory
- p       push a bookmark/directory onto the dir stack
- r       remove saved bookmark
- d       display bookmarked directory path
- sl      print the list of directory bookmarks

Very simple, very effective.

Answer (score 0):

Step further from @Grigory's answer:

```
function cd_up() {
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    cd ..
else
    cd $(printf "%0.s../" $(seq 1 $1 ))
fi
}
alias 'cdd'='cd_up'
```

That is :

```
// go up 1 directory level 
$cdd

// go up 3 directory level 
$cdd 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Got sick of this exact same problem and ended up writing [cd-plus](https://github.com/kevinslin/cd-plus) as a result. A single file CLI utility that lets you cd up multiple directories.

Usage

```
echo `pwd` # /foo/bar/foobar/baz/foobaz/bazfoo
d baz

echo `pwd` # /foo/bar/
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below code to your `.bashrc` will extend `cd`'s completion to honor three plus dot notation

```bash
_cd_dot_expansion() {
    local path="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"

    if [[ "${path}" =~ ^\.{3,} ]]; then
        local dots="${BASH_REMATCH}"
        local levels="${#dots}"
        local tail="${path##*...}"
        local expanded_dots='..'

        # the loop starts at two because the first set of dots is
        # assigned to `expanded_dots` when it is initialized
        for (( i = 2; i < "${levels}"; i++ )); do
            expanded_dots+='/..'
        done

        path="${expanded_dots}${tail}"
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -A file "${path}" ) )

        return
    fi

    _cd
}

complete -o nospace -F _cd_dot_expansion cd
```

Once this snippet is run in your bash shell typing `cd .../` and hitting `<TAB>` will complete the path to `../../` and list the relative paths of all of the directories that are two levels up, for instance.

**Update**: `bash-completion` must be installed to have access to the `_cd` method referenced in the code above.  It's installable via most command line package managers

Answer (score 0):

## For fish shell:

Since no one has made a solution for the fish shell, I'd like to give it a try.

Just making a Fish version out of the answers given here, so consider this, Fish Shell edition.

1st solution is based from [@Grigory K](https://superuser.com/a/819073/912781) answer.

---

### Solution #1

Fish version would be like this:

```bsh
function cd_up
  cd (printf "%.s../" (seq $argv))
end

alias 'cd..'='cd_up'
```

---

### Solution #2 (using a loop)

```bsh
function cd_up
  for i in (seq $argv)
    set -a data "../"
  end
  if test -n "$data"
    cd (string join "" $data)
  end
end
```

You could remove the test branch if you don't want to cover the case where you pass zero.

#### alternative for solution #2

```bsh
function cd_up
  for i in (seq $argv)
    set -a data "../"
  end
  cd (string join "" $data)
end
```

And just add an alias to `cd..` via `alias 'cd..'='cd_up'`

You can edit your fish config via: `vi ~/.config/fish/config.fish`

Answer (score 0):

Please note I am not the first to suggest the `pushd` approach in this thread - I believe that is Richard Homolka.

Use basic Unix tools, but change your strategy. Use `pushd` and friends to keep a ring of directories. Return to them instantly. Don't count anything.

Use `pushd <DIR>` to add a directory to your ring - this becomes your current directory.

Obviously, use `cd` to navigate between directories without affecting your ring.

Empty your ring with `dirs -c`. There will always be one remaining - your current directory.

Use `dirs -l -v` to view your ring.

Remove directories from your ring with `popd` or `popd +N` or `popd -N`.

Rotate your the directories around the ring with `pushd +N`. If L is size of the ring, then for any j in {0..L-1}.

`for ((i=0; i<L; ++i)); do pushd $j; done`

is an idempotent operation on the ring - it returns the ring to its initial state. The size of the ring is always at least L=1, since the current directory is always the first entry.

Use `push -n <DIR>` to insert directories at the position in the ring behind the current directory, so that the current directory does not change.

Finally, make aliases (e.g., `pu`, `po`, and `dv`) that do not conflict which other aliases or commands that are already defined on your(!) environment.

In this example, I make directories {a,b,c} and add the three directories to my ring, which has one to start with - the current directory, for a total of four. I show that rotating your ring at any nonzero position four times in a row is idempotent. I demonstrate the commands mentioned above. I pipe unimportant output to /dev/null. I use curly braces {} to group command output redirection.

```
<0.o>mkdir -p a/b/c

<0.o>{ pushd a; pushd b; pushd c; } > /dev/null

<0.o>dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 1  /home/f41k0r/a/b
 2  /home/f41k0r/a
 3  /home/f41k0r

<0.o>pushd +3 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r
 1  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 2  /home/f41k0r/a/b
 3  /home/f41k0r/a

<0.o>pushd +3 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a
 1  /home/f41k0r
 2  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 3  /home/f41k0r/a/b

<0.o>pushd +3 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a/b
 1  /home/f41k0r/a
 2  /home/f41k0r
 3  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c

<0.o>pushd +3 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 1  /home/f41k0r/a/b
 2  /home/f41k0r/a
 3  /home/f41k0r

<0.o>pushd +2 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a
 1  /home/f41k0r
 2  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 3  /home/f41k0r/a/b

<0.o>pushd +2 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 1  /home/f41k0r/a/b
 2  /home/f41k0r/a
 3  /home/f41k0r

<0.o>pushd +2 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a
 1  /home/f41k0r
 2  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 3  /home/f41k0r/a/b

<0.o>pushd +2 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 1  /home/f41k0r/a/b
 2  /home/f41k0r/a
 3  /home/f41k0r

<0.o>pushd +1 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a/b
 1  /home/f41k0r/a
 2  /home/f41k0r
 3  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c

<0.o>pushd +1 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a
 1  /home/f41k0r
 2  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 3  /home/f41k0r/a/b

<0.o>pushd +1 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r
 1  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 2  /home/f41k0r/a/b
 3  /home/f41k0r/a

<0.o>pushd +1 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 1  /home/f41k0r/a/b
 2  /home/f41k0r/a
 3  /home/f41k0r

<0.o>popd +2 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 1  /home/f41k0r/a/b
 2  /home/f41k0r

<0.o>popd +2 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 1  /home/f41k0r/a/b

<0.o>popd +1 > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 1  /home/f41k0r/a/b

<0.o>pushd -n /home/f41k0r/a > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a/b/c
 1  /home/f41k0r/a
 2  /home/f41k0r/a/b

<0.o>popd > /dev/null; dirs -l -v
 0  /home/f41k0r/a
 1  /home/f41k0r/a/b

<0.o>dirs -c > /dev/null; dirs -l -v

<0.o>pwd
/home/f41k0r/a
```