# Changing directory in script doesn't change directory -- why?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I've seen [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/449687/using-cd-to-go-up-multiple-directory-levels/449705) since searching for this, but initially I wrote this script:

```
for i in `seq 1 $1`; 
   do cd ../;
done;
```

It doesn't change directory. Why is this, running as

```
./updir.sh 5
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I've gone with the function solution with: `function updir() { a=""; for i in `seq 1 $1`; do  a=$a"../"; done; cd $a; }`. This allows use of `cd -` as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running a script as you show creates a copied environment in a sub-shell, and any changes you make, such as setting directories or environment variables, affect only this sub-shell environment, not the calling shell.

In order to make changes to the current shell from a script, you must run the script within the current shell using the `source` or `.` command:

```
. ./updir.sh 5
```

You can make this automatic with an alias:

```
alias updir='. ./updir.sh'
```

Alternatively, you can use a function instead of a script:

```
updir()
{   for i in `seq 1 $1`; 
       do cd ../;
    done
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because scripts are run in a subshell, which keeps track of the current working directory separately. The simplest solution is to use a function:

```
function updir() {
  for i in $(seq 1 $1); do
    cd ..
  done
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my answer crossed with yours, but I am leaving mine because I gave some extra details.