# Is it possible to cd to an ancestor within a directory tree without knowing how far up I need to go?

Tags: git, script, git-bash

I'm writing a script to automate adding, committing, and pushing changes to my submodule and repo. Some submodules are nested further than others and I need to cd back up to the root of the repo. I'm not using the `git submodule foreach` pattern because there may be changes in other submodules that I don't want to commit to them (a quick test) from the branch I'm working on. I have a branch in the super-repo set up for each submodule, conveniently named such that using cd with it will move down to the repo.

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/449687/using-cd-to-go-up-multiple-directory-levels) which has answers that relate to creating and/or aliasing a function to cd up n-levels. I could do something like this as I've already got some aliased functions for other actions, but it would require a different function for every directory or a different script, thus different hotkey, in Git Extensions that's at a different level.

I'm using Git Extensions to manage my repo and it provides a scripting interface in its settings. My current function under the alias in the .git/config:

```
applyupdate = "!f() { \
                      cd \"$1\"/;\
                      git add .;\
                      git commit -m \"$2\";\
                      git push;\
                      cd ..;\ #####this needs to be n levels
                      git add \"$1\";\
                      git commit -m \"$2\";\
                      git push;\
                    }; f"
```

This is executed in Git Extension via a hotkey which runs it with the following arguments:

```
applyupdate {cBrnach} {{UserInput}}
```

where `{cBranch}` will be the active branch or ask for a branch if multiple lie on the same commit in the graph
and `{{UserInput}}` will bring up a dialog to insert a quoted commit message.

Can `cd n-levels` be done with a single function and in a way that I don't need to input how many levels I need to go up? I don't think the `{UserInput}` option in Git Extensions works with multiple inputs.

Comment: Do you always want to go the top of the repository or will `n` vary?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk for that cd statement, it should return to the top of the repo (which could be `n` levels up). This is the only instance where I'm trying to do something like this and I don't think I would need to do this with any other folders.

Comment: You can use this to go the top of the repo: `cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Thanks! Didn't know about that command!

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes, I added an answer with the changes to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Arkadiusz Drabczyk](https://superuser.com/users/328038/arkadiusz-drabczyk) for mentioning `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`.
Changing the script to this works for me:

```
applyupdate = "!f() { \
                      cd \"$1\"/;\
                      git add .;\
                      git commit -m \"$2\";\
                      git push;\
                      cd ..;\ #this gets me out of the submodule
                      cd \"$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)\";\ #this return to super-repo's root
                      git add \"$1\";\
                      git commit -m \"$2\";\
                      git push;\
                    }; f"
```